# Need code to get specific text from url

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, urllib

I am trying to figure out what i need to add to this code so after the url source is read I can eliminate everything but text that is in between  tags and then have have it print results

```
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request('http://myurlhere.com')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print (the_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need an HTML Parser.

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (it supports Python-3.x):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = urllib.request.Request('http://onlinepermits.co.escambia.fl.us/CitizenAccess/Cap/CapDetail.aspx?Module=Building&capID1=14ACC&capID2=00000&capID3=00386&agencyCode=ESCAMBIA')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
print(soup.find('td', id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_PermitDetailList1_owner').div.table.text)
```

Prints:

```
SNB HOTEL INC2607 WILDE LAKE BLVD PENSACOLA FL 32526
```

Comment: ok well I am trying to pull information off of multiple pages that have a title of Owner then after Owner it has a paragraph that is what i need to print is text after Owner it has td tags around it.

Comment: @shoka69 if you would include into the question the relevant part of HTML code - I would provide you with a solution (or throw a link to the website).

Comment: http://onlinepermits.co.escambia.fl.us/CitizenAccess/Cap/CapDetail.aspx?Module=Building&capID1=14ACC&capID2=00000&capID3=00386&agencyCode=ESCAMBIA  where it says Owner

Comment: @shoka69 ok, thanks for the info, this is how you should have initially state the question. See the updated answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: how would I change this code to go to the main site which is http://myescambia.com/business/ds/online-contractor-and-citizen-access and scrape this information of all links 1-9 on this page?